# Function template returns incomplete values

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

what might be wrong with this code?

```
template< typename Tp, const uInt N>
Matrix<Tp,N-1,N-1> minorMatrix_IJ(const Matrix<Tp, N, N>& A, uInt Ith_row, uInt Jth_col)
{
    assert(N > 1);

    Matrix<Tp, N-1,N-1> temp;
    uInt k = 0, m = 0;

    for(uInt i = 0; i < N; i++, k++)
    {
        if(i == Ith_row)
        { 
                if(k > 0) k--;

                continue;
        }

        for(uInt j = 0; j < N; j++, m++)
        {
            if(j == Jth_col)
            { 
                if(m > 0) m--;

                continue;
            }
            temp[k][m] = A[i][j];
            std::cout <<"temp: " << temp[k][m] <<"\n";
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

inside the function temp's values are correctly assigned but returned value gets somehow wrong values. ( Matrix is just a template class with 2d array [rows][cols] ) thanks

Comment: Cannot answer your question without complete code to the Matrix template/class.  Your copy or move constructor probably has a problem as  mentioned by @MattCruikshank below.

Comment: Your assignment operators aren't returning anything.

Comment: i just wrote this code by hand, since for this class compiler generated ctors and copy assignment operators should suffice ?

Comment: That depends on the type of `data`.

Comment: tested with the code above , getting still the same wrong results. datas type is generic type - tested with float

Comment: Awesomely bad indenting.

Comment: What wrong results are you getting? What are you expecting? I'm slightly surprised you're assigning to `temp[k][m]` rather than `temp[m][k]`, but then I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. (And that `if(k > 0)` is redundant, btw.)

Comment: Get rid of the std::move here, it's way too clever, and might honestly be causing you problems.  I see that you assert this != rhs in one of your methods that use std::move, but not the other.

Comment: just found the problem : m,k don't behave as i expected (i was trying to get i,j minor matrix of A) - after continue neither m nor k increments

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Matrix class is not behaving correctly.  Perhaps the copy constructor.

Comment: copy and move copy constructors work correctly , just some values are copied as should be some of them are not